# Ejecutar un .exe dentro de un script de python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero ejecutar un exe desde un script de python, y probé `os.system("")` pero lo malo es que no se ejecutan las siguientes lineas a no ser que cierres el ejecutable, es decir *si el exe no termina, el codigo no sigue*.

Si alguien tiene la solucion se lo agradezco de antemano.

Comment: `os.system("path/ejecutable")` no retorna hasta que el ejecutable termine. Es asi por definición. Puedes revisar `subprocess.Popen` como alternativa (inicia la ejecución, pero retorna de inmediato). Lo otro sería ejecutar `os.system` dentro de un thread separado.

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para ejecutar un programa externo asíncronamente (sin bloquear la ejecución de tu script de Python) puedes crear un objecto de la clase `Popen` del módulo `subprocess` pasándole la ruta del programa. Por ejemplo:

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe")
```

Para ejecutar el programa con parámetros de entrada, sustituye la ruta por una lista con la ruta y sus parámetros:

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe", "documento.txt"])
```

Para esperar a que el programa termine y capturar su salida y sus errores, usa los parámetros `stdout` y `stderr` y la función `communicate`. Por ejemplo:

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "--version"],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                    )

# Salida y errores
out, err = p.communicate(timeout=10)

# Estado de salida. Normalmente, su valor es 0
# si el programa ha terminado con éxito.
exit_code = p.returncode
```

Para terminar el programa desde tu script, utiliza la función `terminate`. Por ejemplo:

```py
p = subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe")
p.terminate()
```

Tienes más detalles en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) oficial de Python (en inglés).

Comment: Que grande, gracias

Comment: De nada, me alegra haber ayudado.